# Python class function as attribute?

Tags: python, class

I have a class and when the class is called I have it do a function in the `__init__` which produces a result. How do I store that result so the rest of the methods can call that variable?

```
class foo:
     def __init__ (self):
         result_needed = some_function()

     def bar (self):
         a= result_needed * 10
         return a
```

I've tried to put the function between `class foo` and `def __init__` that didn't seem to work. I understand attributes go there.

Comment: Hint: store the attribute on `self`. If you haven't seen this pattern before, go back and do some tutorials...

Comment: use ``self.result_needed`` instead of just ``result_needed``. Unlike in many languages, there is no implicit reference to class attributes even if they have the same name.

Comment: got it. thanks. sorry for the stupid question, but it definitely saved me time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `self`

```
class foo:
  def __init__ (self):
     self.result_needed = some_function()

  def bar (self):
     a = self.result_needed * 10
     return a
```